# Reading zip files from Amazon S3 using pre-signed url without knowing object key and bucket name

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a password protected zip file stored in Amazon S3 which I need to read from a python program, extract the csv file from it and read to a dataframe. Initially, I was doing it using the object key and bucket name.

```
import zipfile
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id="<acces_key>",
                        aws_secret_access_key="<secret_key>", region_name="<region>")
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id="<acces_key>",
                                    aws_secret_access_key="<secret_key>", region_name="<region>")


obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="<bucket_name>", Key="<obj_key>")
with io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read()) as tf:

    # rewind the file
    tf.seek(0)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
        df = pd.read_csv(zipf.open('<file_name.csv>', pwd=b'<password>'), sep='|')
        print(df)
```

But due to some security concerns, I won't be able to do this anymore. That is, I won't be having object key and bucket name. And since I wont be having key, I will not have the
`file_name.csv` either. All I will have is a pre-signed URL. Is it possible to read the zip files using pre-signed URLs? How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pre-signed URL` contains all the information you require to download a file. But for that you **don't need to use** `boto3`. Instead you should use regular python tools to [download files](https://www.codementor.io/@aviaryan/downloading-files-from-urls-in-python-77q3bs0un) (or [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/3-simple-ways-to-download-files-with-python-569cb91acae6) )from the internet where `url` will be your pre-signed url.

Comment: Thanks. One more query. Is it only possible to download files from presigned URL? Can I just read the file to a variable using pre-signed URL?

Comment: @elliot You can read them to `BytesIO` buffer, instead of physically saving to your hard drive.